# Coupon Collector Problem with packs

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, coupon-collector

Given the coupon collector's problem, the expected number of coupons is calculated as follows:

$E[X] = N \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{i}$

This assumes we can draw one coupon at a time.

Let's assume one can draw a pack of size $m$. All coupons in a pack are independent, which means there may be duplicates in one pack. In each draw we are only interested in **one** coupon which we do not have yet. All other coupons are discarded for that draw. Drawing packs is repeated until we have all $N$ coupons.

How do I calculate the expected number of draws for that case?

Comment: To check my understanding, do we discard other coupons we do not have yet? And is this procedure repeated however long it takes, that is at least $N$ times?

Comment: Yes, we discard other coupons. Right, the procedure is repeated until we have all coupons. The minimum number of draws is $N$, in which we draw $N$ times a pack of $m$ elements. In each round we found one or more coupons, but we only take one.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. At each draw, are you looking for one *specific* coupon, or are you simply allowed to retain only one unfound coupon from each pack, if there is one? If the latter, the chance of finding any $k+1$-st unfound coupon once $k$ have been found is $1-\left(\frac{k}{N}\right)^m$ (the probability that the draw fails to contain only already-found coupons). If that's the problem, can you take it from there?

Answer (score 2):

There is a matter of interpretation involved. At each draw, are we interested in (i) only one **specific** coupon, or (ii) will any new coupon do? We first solve the problem under the more reasonable interpretation (ii).

Let random variable $W_1$ be the waiting time until the first coupon (clearly $1$), $W_2$ be the waiting time between the first coupon and the second, and so on up to $W_N$.The number $X$ of draws is $W_1+\cdots +W_N$, so $E(X)=E(W_1)+\cdots+E(W_N)$.

Suppose we have $k$ coupons already. Then the probability all $m$ in a pack are not new is $(k/N)^m$. Thus $W_{k+1}$ has geometric distribution with parameter $1-(k/N)^m$, and expectation the reciprocal of this. It follows that
$$E(X)=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{1-(k/N)^m}.$$

Under interpretation (1) the problem is simpler. If at each stage we are only interested in one **specific** coupon, we can assume we want to collect the coupons in the order $1$ to $N$. The probability a pack does not have Coupon $1$ is $\left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^m$, so the probability $p$ that it does is given by $p=1-\left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^m$.

The mean waiting time for Coupon $1$ is $1/p$, so the mean until we get them all the coupons is $N/p$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_i$ be the random variable that counts the number of draws we need to get the ith coupon after we already have (i-1) different coupons.
Then we have \begin{gather}P(X_i=k)=\left(\left(\frac{i-1}{n}\right)^m\right)^{k-1}\cdot\left(1-\left(\frac{i-1}{n}\right)^m\right),\end{gather}
since the probability that in one packages there is not an ith new card is $\Big(\frac{i-1}{n}\Big)^m$.
Now let $X=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$, thus $X$ counts the number of dras one has to do to collect all coupons and so we have to calculate $E(X)$.

The $X_i$´s are geometrically ditributed with $p_i=1-(\frac{i-1}{n})^m$, thus $E(X_i)=\frac1{p_i}$  and since expectation is linear we have \begin{gather}
E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^N E(X_ i)=\sum_{i=1}^N \frac1{p_i}=\sum_{i=1}^N \frac1{1-(\frac{i-1}{n})^m}.
\end{gather}

Comment: You can let parentheses adjust to their content by using `\left` and `\right`.