# Needed subset draws to get all elements with a given probability

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

I have a set of *N* elements. I draw (without replacement) a subset of *M* elements, then replace it.

What value *M* do I need, to have a probability greater than *p* to draw all *N* elements within *X* subset draws?

I found the answer when *M* is 1, but I am not sure how to adapt that in a general case.

Thin coupon problem is different from [Coupon Collector Problem with packs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678841/coupon-collector-problem-with-packs) since we do not have duplicates when we draw a subset.

Comment: If you search the site for coupon collector you will find other versions of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I have no knowledge in probability, I did not know about this classic problem. It will give me a lead to find a solution later when I will have time. I will post the solution here if I find it.

Comment: I found these interesting links: [How many stickers do I need to complete my FIFA Panini album?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101255/how-many-stickers-do-i-need-to-complete-my-fifa-panini-album) and [A variation of the coupon collector's problem for Panini Albums?](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/cow93r/a_variation_of_the_coupon_collectors_problem_for/).